# Does mysqldump return a status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

I am creating a script that backups a mysql db using the mysqldump utility. I am writing this script in the shell "sh". I would like to capture the output status of mysqldump in the script (i.e. if the mysqldump command failed or succeeded) so I can report if the script was successful or not.

- Does mysqldump return an output status?
- Can someone please give me
  instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

although there seems to be no particular documentation about it, mysqldump yields an exit code of 0 on success and != 0 on error, as is conventional for console applications.

You'd use it like e.g.:

```
 mysqldump -q -h host -u user database  >db_dump.sql
 EXITCODE=$?
 if [ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ] ; then 
      echo "mysqldump failed with exit code $EXITCODE"
 else
      echo "mysqldump finished ok"
 fi
```